# Stale BigQuery table after load job

Tags: google-bigquery

I've ran into a situation where a BigQuery table has become stale. I can't even run a count query on it. This occurred right after I ran the first load job.

For each query I run I get an error:

> Error: Unexpected. Please try again.

See for example Job IDs: job_OnkmhMzDeGpAQvG4VLEmCO-IzoY, job_y0tHM-Zjy1QSZ84Ek_3BxJ7Zg7U

Answer (score 0):

The error is "illegal field name". It looks like the field 69860107_VID is causing it. BigQuery doesn't support column rename, so if you want to change the schema you'll need to recreate the table.

I've filed a bug to fix the internal error -- this should have been blocked when the table was created.